# If I push a function call into an array or assign as a property does it push/assign the returned value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

Example:

```
function SomeCall(){
      return "Bill";
}

var a = [];
a.push(SomeCall());

var obj = {
      name: SomeCall()
};

//is function CALLED here or does this already contain "Bill"?
console.log(obj.name); 
console.log(a[0]); //what about here?
```

Now when I access the value of the object or the item in the array, is it calling the function at that time and giving me the value? Or is it calling the function at the time of the push/assignment and holding the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a non-lazy language, so when you code a call to a function into a call to another function, the effect is that the **result** of the inner function call is passed to the outer function.

Thus:

```
a.push(SomeCall());
```

is effectively like:

```
var temp = SomeCall(); // call function, get result
a.push(temp);
```

Similarly, in an object literal expression the right-hand sides of the property declarations are evaluated, and the results of the evaluations are the values of the properties.

Comment: What about the property assignment?

Answer (score 3):

The function is called right when the `()` is used. So the array contains the return value of the function. If you want to store the function itself, just use `a.push(SomeCall)` and call it later (`a[0]()`). In case you always want to call it with certain params, store an anonymous function containing the call:

```
a.push(function() {
    return SomeCall(your, params);
});
```

However, in modern JS engines (i.e. not in "old" IE versions) you can define *accessors* however. This allows you to execute code when a certain property is read (or written):

```
var obj = {};
obj.__defineGetter__("name", SomeCall);
```

Then any read access to `obj.name` will return the result of `SomeCall()`.